# Creating objects with parameters in Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, collections, parameters, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to create objects with parameters while using Stream class? I'd like to reproduce the following with Java 8 Stream.

```
for(Integer id:someCollectionContainingTheIntegers){
     someClass.getList().add(new Whatever(param1, id));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. But if you have a collection, you can use `forEach` and a lambda:

```
someCollectionContainingTheIntegers.forEach(id -> someClass.getList().add(new Whatever(param1, id));
```

Another possible variation is to collect into the destination list:

```
someCollectionContainingTheIntegers.stream()
    .map(id -> new Whatever(param1, id))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> someClass.getList()));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Janos :)

Answer (score 2):

One more solution...

```
    List<Whatever> collect = someCollectionContainingTheIntegers.stream()
            .map(id -> new Whatever(param1, id))
            .collect(toList());
    someClass.getList().addAll(collect);
```

Answer (score 1):

do a foreach in the list

```
List<Integer> ml = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
List<Integer> ml2 = Arrays.asList(21, 22, 23, 24);
ml2.forEach(x -> ml.add(x));
System.out.println(ml);
```